# HttpException occurred: File does not exist

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have a Silverlight/ASP hosted app.  When I start, I get the error:

```
HttpException occurred

File does not exist.
```

This just started happening yesterday, and I have no idea why.  It's not even getting to my code, just internal calls starting with WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest.

Running VS2010, the app is .NET 4.0

I would appreciate any help- I have real bugs to fix ASAP!

Cheers,
Daniel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it, and here's how:

> Run the app and immediately get the error
>
> Turned on Call Stack Window (Debug->Windows->Call Stack)
>
> Top of the stack is a call to System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo
>
> Went to Locals Window (Debug->Windows->Locals) did not see anything meaningful there
>
> Went up the stack once to ProcessRequestInternal
>
> Looked in Locals Window, opened up variable called "context"
> browsed through properties...
> in ConfigurationPath I see a path to a file:  /ClientBin/Images/pclogo.png
>
> Sure enough, that image file not there!
>
> Copy the file, and all  is well.  Whew!

Next just need to fix the project by making sure the image is treated as content.  Still, such a slog to find an obvious and common error.

Comment: +1 for helping troubleshoot, though it didn't work for me.  I find it beyond amazing that when they throw this error, they don't put the filename in any form into the exception message.

Comment: @Mike K I would have +100'd your comment if they let me.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by looking at Daniel Williams solution. 
In my case it was looking for faviicon.ico 
This is when I debug using Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Daniel wrote, (which worked for me), since my SL4 app doesn't require ASP.NET, I simply unchecked the ASP.NET debugger from within the web app. The light bulb went off after realizing that SL4 doesn't support .ico files.

Comment: Worked for me, on a SL5 app without ASP.NET. I did however +1 Daniel's answer for sheer complexity!